# What were the original titles/structure in The Rime of the Ancient Mariner?

Tags: samuel-taylor-coleridge, poetry

Coleridge's famous poem "The Rime of the Ancient Mariner" has its constituent parts titled differently in different editions / online sources. For example:

- [Lit2Go](http://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/181/the-rime-of-the-ancient-mariner/) has "Part the First", "Part the Second", and so on.
- [Poetry Foundation](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/43997/the-rime-of-the-ancient-mariner-text-of-1834) has "Part I", "Part II", and so on.
- [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/151/151-h/151-h.htm) has "Part the First", "Part the Second", and so on.
- [Poets' Graves](https://www.poetsgraves.co.uk/Classic%20Poems/Coleridge/the_rime_of_the_ancient_mariner.htm) has "Part I", "Part II", and so on.

What is the *original* version here? **How were the parts titled when the poem was first published?**

Comment: One can actually see the original formatting in the original publication by looking on [Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=p98NAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=lyrical+ballads+coleridge&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp76_Lx-nYAhVNS60KHQhuCqsQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=ancyent%20marinere&f=false). The sections were labelled I, II, etc. Project Gutenberg probably would not have changed their title formats capriciously.

Comment: @PeterShor I found a few Google Books hits, but I don't know how to distinguish the *original* version from the hundreds of others floating around the internet. That said, it sounds like you have enough info/knowledge for an answer here ...

Comment: Shor's edition is the same 1798 London edition my belated post mentions. In general, with google books, if you click on the "about this book" button you get some bibliographic info.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rime_of_the_Ancient_Mariner) says it was first published in 1798, and published in a [revised version](https://books.google.com/books?id=lidEAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=samuel+taylor+coleridge+1817+rime+of+the+ancient&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuuODy-enYAhVBneAKHWiQBfEQ6AEINDAC#v=snippet&q=part%20the%20second&f=false) in 1817. (Coleridge was still alive then.) The revised version uses "Part the second," etc., and has changed some of the even-then-archaic spelling. I don't know whether there were any more substantial changes.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an exact answer to the original question.

TROTAM was first published in Bristol in 1798 in a collection by Coleridge and Wordsworth, *Lyrical Ballads*.  As one might expect, the very first edition is rare, and subsequent editions numerous.  The earliest version I have found on-line is of a [1798 London](https://archive.org/stream/lyricalballadswi00word#page/n17/mode/2up)
edition.   It titles the poem as ""THE RIME OF THE ANCYENT MARINERE,/ IN SEVEN PARTS." The parts are labelled simply "I." , "II.", on up through "VII.", (without the word *part*) each starting on a fresh page, with fancy rules above and  below the  numbers.